How to iterate over BVH nodes using embree API?
I want to draw individual bounds of each node of the BVH. How do I do it in embree?
This tutorial  seems to be what I want, but I don't understand what's happening here. It's using structures that are not present in the API.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
